# Create txt Document C++

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to create a txt document and put some text in it.  However, on lines 10, 25 and 26 (which I'll put a comment next to), I'm getting errors.  Please help, and thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string textFileName = "SavedPasswords.txt";

    ofstream textFile(textFileName);//10

    textFile << "Password1" << endl << "Password2" << endl;

    textFile.close();

    string directory;
    size_t path = textFileName.rfind("\\");

    if(string::npos != path)
    {
        directory = textFileName.substr(0, path);
    }

    system("cd\\");
    system("cd " + directory);//25
    system("start " + textFileName);//26
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\SavePasswords\main.cpp|10|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream::basic_ofstream(std::string&)'|

C:\Users\User\Desktop\SavePasswords\main.cpp|25|error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'|

C:\Users\User\Desktop\SavePasswords\main.cpp|26|error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'|
```

Comment: Compiler errors? What errors are you receiving? It would help if you added that to your question.

Comment: Posted the errors below.

Comment: What are lines 10, 25, and 26?

Comment: You should [edit] those into your original question, not post an *answer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for `ofstream` requires a `char*` instead of a `string`. You can easily get a `char*` from your `string` with the `c_str()` member function:

```
ofstream textFile(textFileName.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks, the error's gone!  What about the system stuff I did?

Comment: @onlineone22 If you have another problem, you should post a new question. Also be sure to accept my answer when the site allows you.

Comment: the question was asking to fix all the errors in the code, not just the first one like you did.

Comment: @onlineone22 This change should have fixed all of the errors which you posted in your question. If you are getting different errors now, you need to post a new question, as I said before.

Comment: I believe I stated that 3 lines were getting errors.  "However, on lines 10, 25 and 26 (which I'll put a comment next to), I'm getting errors."  You fixed only the line 10 error.

Comment: @onlineone22 oic...the other two errors are very similar to the first one. See if you can use my suggestion for fixing the first error to find a solutions for the other two on your own.

Comment: Sorry Code, I'm pretty new to scripting in general, and this script is a big step up from me.  I hardly understand a lot of the stuff on it.  I've experimented a little, and still can't find out how to make it work.  Can you please hold my hand and help me through this?  Thanks.

Comment: @onlineone22 Part of the difficulty is that you are doing several things in a single line of code in your `system()` calls. Since you are just learning, you should break each of these lines into two lines. First, build the `string` you want to use a command, then call `system()` to execute the command.

Comment: still have errors.  Am I getting any closer?  string systemCommands[3] = {"cd\\",
    "cd " + directory,
    "start " + textFileName};

    system(systemCommands[0]);
    system(systemCommands[1]);
    system(systemCommands[2]);

Comment: @onlineone22 Yes, you are closer. There is one last thing you need to fix. Read my answer again to see how it applies to your new code.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you, but after over 30 minutes of trying, I still can't figure out how to apply it to my new code.